# How to get unique pairs in SQL when there is many to many relationship in data

Tags: sql, sap-iq, sybase-asa

I have following data. I need to make unique pairs.

```
element1        element2
E1              C1
E1              C2
E2              C1
E2              C2
E3              C1
E3              C2
```

How can I use SQL to get pairs as follows:

```
E1,C1    E2,C2   Discard E3
```

Comment: Are we defining "unique" as "the number part matches"?

Comment: Element1 and Element2 are columns in same table

Comment: You need recursive CTEs for this problem.  I don't think Sybase supports them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
select distinct a.element1, b.element2
from (
  select element1, dense_rank() over(order by element1) as rank
  from my_table
) a
join (
  select element2, dense_rank() over(order by element2) as rank
  from my_table
) b on a.rank = b.rank
```

Comment: Above code does not work. It only gives me E1,C1 and not E2, C2

Comment: I'm sorry I can't really test it. I have SAP ASE, but not SAP ASA.

Comment: If you run the inner queries separately, do you get `rank`: (1, 2, 3) for the first one, and (1, 2) for the second one?